# Emulate Sleeping Windows Mobile Device

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, emulation

Is it possible to emulate a device sleeping and waking using the Microsoft-supplied device emulators?

Comment: Have you tried singing a it a lullaby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to generate your own emulator image with a modified kernel (changing OEMPowerOff).  Bruce Eitman [blogged about it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217202058/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BruceEitman/archive/2008/08/11/platform-builder-getting-the-emulator-to-resume.aspx).  You didn't detail your needs, so it's hard to say, but you might be able to provide some form of simulation by manually setting the named power management events.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but in case anyone else stumbles across it, you *can* make the Windows Mobile emulators 'sleep' and wake up, though not with the debugger attached.

1. Close the emulator window while your application is running and save the state.  Or, configure power management to sleep the emulator at the desired time; the emulator will close and save its state automatically.  If the debugger is attached, it will lose its connection and stop debugging.
2. Open Device Emulator Manager and click Refresh until the emulator shows up as disconnected (no icon next to it).  Right-click on the emulator name and select Connect.
3. Emulator wakes up and reappears.  If your application is listening for the wake-up notification, it will be signaled at this point.

You can also wake up the emulator using Debug > Attach to Process, though this does not always succeed.  Either way, by the time the debugger attaches, the wake up sequence will already have executed.  If you can get by with debug statements, though, this is easier than modding the emulator image.